# Solving a calculation with a java string

Tags: java, string

so I am looking for advice on how to solve a calculation that is entered as a String in Java.

For example: "50 * 6 - 75 / 25" is entered I am then needing to solve this calculation using bodmas to.

So (50*6)-(75/25)

Answer = 297

I didn't explain it very well but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BeanShell's Interpreter class to do this.

```
new Interpreter().eval("50 * 6 - 75 / 25");
```

Or you can also use the java's inbuilt JavaScript engine, an example of which is shown below

[Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)